# Django Social Authentication Create New User With Custom Model

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I'm trying to develop a web goole social authentication feature that uses a custom Django user model and dj-rest-auth and django-allauth as social authentication packages.

My custom user model is called 'Account' and it inherits from the AbstractBaseUser class. The Account model is shown below

models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password, nickname=None, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("이메일을 입력해 주세요")
        
        if not nickname:
            nickname = kwargs.get('email')
        
        user = self.model(
            email = email,
            nickname = nickname,
        )
        
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, email=None, password=None, nickname="슈퍼", **extra_fields):
        superuser = self.create_user(
            email = email,
            password = password,
            nickname = nickname,
        )
        superuser.is_staff = True
        superuser.is_superuser = True
        superuser.is_active = True
        
        superuser.save(using=self._db)
        return superuser
    
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    objects = UserManager()
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import User, Post


User = get_user_model()
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(  # type: ignore
            nickname = validated_data['nickname'],
            email = validated_data['email'],
            password = validated_data['password']
        )
        
        return user
    
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
state = STATE
BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URI = BASE_URL + 'market/google/callback/'

def google_login(request):
    scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
    client_id = GOOGLE_ID
    return redirect(f"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URI}&scope={scope}")
    
def google_callback(request):
    client_id = GOOGLE_ID
    client_secret = GOOGLE_PW
    code = request.GET.get('code')

    token_req = requests.post(f"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&code={code}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri={GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URI}&state={state}")
    
    token_req_json = token_req.json()
    error = token_req_json.get("error")
    
    if error is not None:
        raise JSONDecodeError(error)  # type: ignore
    
    access_token = token_req_json.get("access_token")
    
    email_req = requests.get(f"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={access_token}")
    email_req_status = email_req.status_code
    
    if email_req_status != 200:
        return JsonResponse({'err_msg': 'failed to get email'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    
    email_req_json = email_req.json()
    email = email_req_json.get("email")
    
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        
        socail_user = SocialAccount.objects.get(user=user)
        
        if socail_user.provider != "google":
            return JsonResponse({'err_msg': 'no matching social type'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        
        
        data = {'access_token': access_token, 'code': code}
        accept = requests.post(f"{BASE_URL}market/google/login/finish/", data=data)
        accept_status = accept.status_code
        
        if accept_status != 200:
            return JsonResponse({'err_msg': 'failed to signin'}, status=accept_status)

        accept_json = accept.json()
        accept_json.pop("user", None)
        return JsonResponse(accept_json)
    
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        data = {'access_token': access_token, 'code': code}
        accept = requests.post(f"{BASE_URL}market/google/login/finish/", data=data)
        accept_status = accept.status_code
        
        if accept_status != 200:
            return JsonResponse({'err_msg': 'failed to signup'}, status=accept_status)

        accept_json = accept.json()
        accept_json.pop('user', None)
        return JsonResponse(accept_json)
    
    except SocialAccount.DoesNotExist:  # type: ignore
        return JsonResponse({'err_msg': 'email exists but not social user'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    
from dj_rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.oauth2.client import OAuth2Client
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.google import views as google_view

class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = google_view.GoogleOAuth2Adapter
    callback_url = GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URI
    client_class = OAuth2Client
```

When registering as a member using google social login, when the google_callback function is called, I want to enter an email in the nickname field. The error message states:

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: market_user.nickname

I tried many times, but I couldn't put any value in the nickname field.

please help thank you so much

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password, nickname=None, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("이메일을 입력해 주세요")
        
        if not nickname:
            nickname = kwargs.get('email')
        
        user = self.model(
            email = email,
            nickname = nickname,
        )
        
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

When there is no nickname, an attempt was made to get an email and receive input, but it failed.

I tried to save it by passing it as an access_token to the google_callback function, but it failed.